# How can I repeat with a pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace certain words with spaces through regular expressions.
E.g I have the following code to replace the word `"onerror=error="` with a space.

```java
String content = "ononerror=error=";
Pattern scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("onerror(.*?)=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
content = scriptPattern.matcher(content).replaceAll("");
```

If you run the code as above, only "onerror" remains.

But I want to replace it and replace the "onerror" that came out again with a space.

In other words, I want to replace "onerror" with a regular expression and finally leave only a space.

I don't know which keyword to search for, so I ask a question. Please help me.

---

This code is rewritten using find (). Please note.

```java
Pattern scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("onerror(.*?)=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
while (scriptPattern.matcher(content).find()) {
    content = scriptPattern.matcher(content).replaceAll("");
}

scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("onchange(.*?)=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
while (scriptPattern.matcher(content).find()) {
    content = scriptPattern.matcher(content).replaceAll("");
}

scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("onclick(.*?)=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
while (scriptPattern.matcher(content).find()) {
    content = scriptPattern.matcher(content).replaceAll("");
}
```

Comment: Run the logic in a loop?

Comment: @CinCout I thought of a loop, but I'm not sure how to repeat it by checking if there are any words left in the word to replace.

Comment: Hint: The output of ith iteration becomes the input string for the i+1th iteration

Comment: @CinCout It looks like i can run a while loop with find () in the matcher. I think this can be solved, but I want to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Sounds good, why don't you try it?

Comment: @CinCout I didn't know the existence of find () because I didn't know which keyword to look for. Thanks for your comment. Thank you.

Comment: If you can give examples of your input and the expected outputs, we might be able to define a single regex to solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the input and output samples are unstructured. I'm just trying to clear things that start with `on` to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: Running individual loops might be slower, but it will do the trick

Comment: @CinCout Slowing down is inevitable. Okay. Thank you so much for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop using `find()` could do the trick:

```
String content = "ononerror=error=";
Pattern scriptPattern = Pattern.compile("onerror(.*?)=", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
while (scriptPattern.matcher(content).find()) {
    content = scriptPattern.matcher(content).replaceAll("");
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I can find find(). In addition, I have a question. If i need to replace multiple words like onchange in addition to onerror, is it best to use multiple while statements?

Comment: I didn't know how to display the code in the comments, so I wrote it above. Please note that...

Comment: You should edit your question to add any extra queries.